# Simple Chrome or Safari-like tabs implementation for Cocoa on OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, tabs

I was wondering if there was a simple tab implementation for OS X/Cocoa/Objective-C visually similar to either the one in Chrome or Safari.

I tried searching but didn't find much except [chromium-tabs](https://github.com/rsms/chromium-tabs), which are buggy (see my unanswered [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685238/chromium-tabs-cant-update-tab-icon), which is not the only bug I found in it, but certainly one of the deal breakers), and [PSMTabBarControl](http://www.positivespinmedia.com/dev/PSMTabBarControl.html) which seems to be abandonned now.

Comment: Check out SFTabView(https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/sftabview) -- it creates tabs that look similar to Chrome's tabs, and the codebase seems reasonably tidy, so perhaps you could work off of that.

Comment: Tristan, please post this as an answer.